# How to get row Index from cellEdited:function(cell)? - Tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have a typical tabulator setup with  `keybindings:{"navUp" :"38","navDown" :"40","navLeft" :"37","navRight" :"39"}` enabled.

When edit a cell it updates data successfully and moves programmatic in the next cell bellow

```
    cellEdited:function(cell){
            
         let updateValue = updateValueQuery(columnIndex,rowIndex,cell.getValue()).then(function(done){
         cell.nav().down();
         });
    }
```

When in a new cell down, the rowId doesn't change (its behavior is not like rowClick)

What i'm trying to figure out is:  How to get `row.getIndex();` inside of `cellEdited:function(cell){}`

```
    cellEdited:function(cell){

         // ->> How i can obtain rowIndex = row.getIndex(); here or if there is another more optimal way.

         let updateValue = updateValueQuery(columnIndex,rowIndex,cell.getValue()).then(function(done){
         cell.nav().down();
         });
    }
```

I've tried to put row attribute in `cellEdited:function(cell,row)` but without luck.

Any help will be appreciated!
thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question but you can access the row through the [cell component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/components#component-cell) methods

```
var row = cell.getRow();
```

And you can also just get the data without going through the row:

> **Get Data**
>
> The getData function returns the data for the row that contains the
> cell.

```
var dataID = cell.getData().id; 
// the name of the property you are using for the index
```

Or use `getIndex`

> **Get Index**
>
> The getIndex function returns the index value for the row. (this is
> the value from the defined index column, NOT the row's position in the
> table)

```
var rowIndex = row.getIndex();
```

If you want to get the next or previous logical row, you can use the methods of the [row component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/components#component-row):

> **Get Next Row**
>
> The getNextRow function returns the Row Component for the next visible
> row in the table, if there is no next row it will return a value of
> false.

```
var nextRow = row.getNextRow();
var prevRow = row.getPrevRow();
```

And finally:

> **Get Position**
>
> Use the getPosition function to retrieve the numerical position of a
> row in the table. By default this will return the position of the row
> in all data, including data currently filtered out of the table.
>
> If you want to get the position of the row in the currently
> filtered/sorted data, you can pass a value of true to the optional
> first argument of the function.

```
var rowPosition = row.getPosition(true); 
//return the position of the row in the filtered/sorted data
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, what i'm trying to do is to get row.getIndex(); inside of cellEdited:function(cell){}, apparently the function has only access to (cell) attributes. Is there any way of getting the indexID using cell object access? Something like: cell.getRow.index().

Comment: @GeorgeGotsidis - Reread my answer: if you have the cell reference you can access the row.

Comment: what did the trick was cell.getRow().getIndex(); thank you for your prompt answer!